# How do I Change the Order Scripts / css get inserted During Compile with NG Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngboilerplate

I'm using NG Boilerplate to create an angularJs application and I'm running into an issue where the JS file containing my login controller gets written to index.html before the loginModule.js file does and this is causing a bunch of errors.

Is there a way to control the order in which JS (and CSS) files get added to the compiled page?

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem too.

The JS files are added alphabetically per module to your index.html. I solved this problem by **defining submodules in files that start with an underscore** (like _submodule.js) to ensure that it gets added to index.html before the other files that use this module.

More info here: https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/issues/152

From this thread:

[...] I needed a solution for multi-file modules and came up with something that seems to be working. In a multi-file module folder, I create an _init.js which declares the module:

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.about', [
  'ui.state',
  'placeholders',
  'ui.bootstrap'
])

;
```

And then my other .js files can do this:

```
angular.module('ngBoilerplate.about')

.controller ...

;
```